# scipy.optimize.curve_fit raises RuntimeWarning

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve by changing two parameters (`e` and `A`). The target curve is plotted by assigning `n0=0.395`, but its actual value is `0.0395`. So I am hoping to achieve the same curve by changing `e` and `A`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x,e,A):
    return A*(e+x)**0.0395 

strain = np.linspace(0,15,3000) # variable
e = 0.773
A = 386.5
n0 = 0.395
y = A*(e+strain)**n0 # target to minimize
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, strain, y)
```

However, I constantly get this warning after running the code:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return A*(e+x)**0.0395
```

I was wondering why this happens and how should improve the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that I do not like, but it does eliminate the warning. I found that, strangely to me, "e" was being made negative within curve_fit(). I added a "brick wall" inside the function to stop this, but it should be unnecessary. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x,e,A):
    if e < 0.0: # curve_fit() hits a "brick wall" if e is negative
        return 1.0E10 # large value gives large error, the "brick wall"
    return A*(e+x)**0.0395 

strain = np.linspace(0,0.1,3) # variable
e = 0.773
A = 386.5
n0 = 0.395
y = A*(e+strain)**n0 # target to minimize
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, strain, y)
```